# Using select tag as navigation to other pages?

Tags: jquery, select, anchor

I need to make my navigation of this website work from a drop down select tag. I realise this will involve a bit a jQuery. this is how my HTML looks so far :

```
<div id="top_nav">
<select>
 <option value="">1</option>
 <option value="">2</option>
 <option value="">3</option>
 <option value="">4</option>
 <option value="">5</option>
 <option value="">Contact</option>
 </select>
```

So when user selects 2 for example, it takes them to page 2 of the site. Any help with this much appreciated.

Thanks
Angela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery on your page, you can do like that:

```
<div id="top_nav">
    <select>
        <option value="page1.html">1</option>
        <option value="page2.html">2</option>
        <option value="page3.html">3</option>
        <option value="page4.html">4</option>
        <option value="page5.html">5</option>
        <option value="contact.html">Contact</option>
    </select>
</div>

$('#top_nav select').change(function(){
    window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="selectId " onChange="redirect()">
 <option value="">1</option>
 <option value="">2</option>
 <option value="">3</option>
 <option value="">4</option>
 <option value="">5</option>
 <option value="">Contact</option>
 </select>


    function redirect()
    {
     window.location.href=$('#selectId :selected').text()"+.html";
    }
```

If it is value based then use

```
    window.location.href=$('#selectId').val()"+.html";
```

Comment: I would put the html links value into the Value, then key off of the value.

Comment: If I'm using page name do I change pageNo to pageName ?

Answer (score 0):

well theres more than one way. you can use `.html()` or `.val()` html being `<option>here</option>`. and val being `<option value="here"></option>`

```
$('select','#top_nav').change(function(){
    document.location=$('select','#top_nav').html()+'.html';
});
```